# Arraylist add/remove view in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, expo

Currently I do have such kind of code. Check out here: https://snack.expo.io/H1gGDfhEpB . The basic idea behind this feature is, to show/remove view by clicking to icon. Every view is individual in the concept. I mean the first view can remove himself, the second view can also remove himself and etc. Besides, if the first view can add the second view, the second view can also add third value. The maximum amount of view is set to be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated example: (created ContactItem Component and itemsCount property)
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/crabby-orangew

Comment: thank you for your answer, check out this screenshot: https://ibb.co/N3P98r8 .
Maybe you didn't understand me. restate logic: if the first icon is clicked, it should change himself to another icon and add second view. Also this first icon should be able to remove himself.